# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when using NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c

Error happens when writing in NSUserDefaults.

Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x2166b8f5)

I have google it but can't find any other clue to solve.

my iOS version is 7.0.4 xcode is 5.1.1
my source code is like this below.

```
CCLOG(@"%@",message);
NSNumber *highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"highscore"];
if (self.score > [highScore intValue]) {
    // new highscore!
    highScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.score];
    //something bad in this code.

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScore forKey:@"highscore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why create an NSNumber first? Is this running on the main thread? What is self.score (definition and logged value)?

Comment: What is value of highScore if u log it?

Comment: @JamalZafar according to the screenshot, the value is 4988.

Comment: A stack trace or "Enable Zombie Objects" would help :D